# Splicing a specific entry

Tags: javascript

Title says it all,
I'm trying to remove an specific entry, for example an entry ofwhich the users id is 1.

I've made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqntaqbt/8/) to demostrate how it isn't working, for some reason not every message gets removed but there's always one left.

```
var messages = [
    {
    user:1,
    message:'hello'
  },
  {
    user:1,
    message:'hello'
  },
  {
    user:1,
    message:'hello'
  }
];

messages.forEach(function(message, index){
  console.log(message.message);

  if(message.user === 1){
    console.log('remove this message!');
    messages.splice(index, 1);
  }
});

console.log(messages);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is using the function **[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**:

```js
var messages = [{    user: 1,    message: 'hello'  },  {    user: 1,    message: 'hello'  },  {    user: 3,    message: 'hello'  }],
    result = messages.filter(({user}) => user !== 1);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Your approach using the function [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):**

*The problem is the modification you're applying to the array using the function **[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**, the length of that array is modified as well.*

An alternative is decreasing the index using a `for-loop`.

```js
var messages = [{    user: 6,    message: 'hello'  },{    user: 1,    message: 'hello'  },  {    user: 3,    message: 'hello'  },  {    user: 1,    message: 'hello'  },  {    user: 4,    message: 'hello'  }];

for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  if (messages[i].user === 1) messages.splice(i--, 1);
}

console.log(messages);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code I had provided tho, why does it not work?

Edit: also your code still outputs a message.

Comment: @OrpheuZ is an example, I've put a `user === 3`

Answer (score 1):

You're removing items from the array while iterating through it, which is confusing the iteration:

The first step of the iteration removes the first element in the array, shifting every remaining element by one.  The second step of the iteration looks at the second element in the array... which used to be the third element before you shortened the array. The iterator therefore never sees the (original) second element.

One way to work around this this is to start at the end of the array and work towards the beginning; that way changes in the array length don't matter, as they'll only affect elements you've already iterated over.

```js
var messages = [
    {
    user:1,
    message:'A'
  },
  {
    user:1,
    message:'B'
  },
  {
    user:1,
    message:'C'
  }
];

for (var i=messages.length-1; i>-1; i--) {
  var message = messages[i];
  if(message.user === 1){
    console.log('remove this message!');
    messages.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(messages);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var messages = [
    {
    user:1,
    message:'hello'
  },
  {
    user: 2,
    message:'hello'
  },
  {
    user: 3,
    message:'hello'
  }
];

var newMessages = messages.filter(message => message.user !== 1);
console.log(newMessages);
```

With your method, you're modifying the array on the fly which led to inconsistencies.